# Subversion svn protocol

Tags: svn, url, tortoisesvn

I have recently installed `svn server` (Collabnet server) on some machine X (for example its host name is s-concrete_name). There's a network share. Is it alright that I can only connect with server from a client machine using the following url: svn://s-concrete_name/E:my_repository_folder?
Should a drive letter be present in the url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If `svnserve` is installed on the server and used to access the repo, the URL should look like `svn://machine.company.com/my_repo`. SVN is often accessed through HTTP, though. Are you sure you installed and configured svnserve?

See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html for installation instructions. Did you follow these steps?